# Using other languages with Rails?

Tags: php, python, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, perl

I'm trying to make a Web site that showcases multiple scripting languages, including Ruby on Rails.  If I make the framework of the site in Rails, is there a way to run other languages like PHP on the Rails server, or do I need something like XAMPP?

Comment: As long as you are having php binary on your server, you can run code with it and catch the output.

Comment: Can you give us a little more context? I.E why are you calling the languages?

Answer (score 1):

For example when you want to run [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), you could use [`Microperl`](http://www.shlomifish.org/microperl-web-repl-v1/repl.html). For [`php`](http://phpjs.org/).

If this all does not work for you or you want to execute it otherwise, you can create APIs in such languages and let Ruby talk to this APIs.